# JPA JoinTable Cannot Access List of Associated Entities?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jax-rs

I'm a beginner in databasing and JPA. My problem is that when querying for a 'Project', I cannot access that Project's list of enabled 'Api[s]'. Specifically, when I use a named query to get a result list, the code fails at this line with the following error.

Line inside of a @GET method inside of a stateless bean :

```
List<Project> resultList =  em.createNamedQuery("Project.queryAllUtorid").setParameter("userid", "a valid user I put into the db").getResultList();
List<Api> apis = resultList.get(i).getActiveapis();
System.out.println("Size of list: " + apis.size()); //Fails here
```

Error:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException: Internal Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: "T1.APPID" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.16.53 Error Code: -206 Call: SELECT t1.APIID, t1.APINAME, t1.BASEURL, t1.QUOTA FROM ACTIVEAPIS t0, DB2ADMIN.APIS t1 WHERE ((t0.PROJECTID = ?) AND (t1.APPID = t0.APIID)) bind => [1 parameter bound] Query: ReadAllQuery(name="activeapis" referenceClass=Api sql="SELECT t1.APIID, t1.APINAME, t1.BASEURL, t1.QUOTA FROM ACTIVEAPIS t0, DB2ADMIN.APIS t1 WHERE ((t0.PROJECTID = ?) AND (t1.APPID = t0.APIID))")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
at [internal classes]
at ConsoleREST.queryAllUserProjects(ConsoleREST.java:41)
```

I understand that Error Code -206 means that a column is not specified or is missing. This is obvious because the Select statement is being applied to ACTIVEAPIS with the parameters of an API. I'm not at all sure how to proceed. I looked at various examples and I cannot spot the 'difference' between my code and example code.

I have three tables: PROJECTS, APIS, ACTIVEAPIS in a db2 database. Below are their definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS(
PROJECTID   INTEGER     NOT NULL UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 10000, INCREMENT BY 1),
PROJECTNAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
USERID      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CREATEDAT   TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL generated always for each row on update as row change timestamp,
CONSTRAINT FK_USERID FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USERS (USERID)
);

CREATE TABLE APIS(
APIID   INTEGER         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
APINAME VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
QUOTA   INTEGER         NOT NULL,
BASEURL     VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT PK_APIID PRIMARY KEY (APIID)
);

CREATE TABLE ACTIVEAPIS(
APIID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
PROJECTID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_APIID_PROJECTID PRIMARY KEY (APIID, PROJECTID),
CONSTRAINT FK_APIID     FOREIGN KEY (APIID)     REFERENCES  APIS        (APIID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PROJECTID FOREIGN KEY (PROJECTID) REFERENCES  PROJECTS    (PROJECTID)
);
```

The entities:

Project Entity:

```
public class Project implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PROJECTID")
    private Integer projectid;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "PROJECTNAME")
    private String projectname;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "CREATEDAT", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Api
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="ACTIVEAPIS",
        joinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="PROJECTID", referencedColumnName="PROJECTID")
            }, 
            inverseJoinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="APIID", referencedColumnName="APPID")
            }
        )
    private List<Api> activeapis;

public List<Api> getActiveapis() { return activeapis; }

... getters, settings, toString, equals, hashCode
}
```

Api Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APIS", schema="DB2ADMIN")
public class Api implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "APIID")
    private Integer apiid;

    @Column(name = "APINAME")
    private String apiname;

    @Column(name = "QUOTA")
    private int quota;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "BASEURL", unique = true)
    private String baseurl;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Project
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="activeapis")
    private List<Project> projects;

    public Api() { super(); }

    public Integer getApiid() { 
        if( apiid == null ) return -1;
        return apiid;
    }
```

JAX-RS Setup

```
@GET
@Path("project")
@Produces("text/json")
public String queryAllUserProjects(@CookieParam(value = "UID") String userid){
    List<Project> resultList =  em.createNamedQuery("Project.queryAllUserid").setParameter("userid", userid).getResultList();
    String json = "[";
    for ( int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++ ) {
        List<Api> apis = resultList.get(i).getActiveapis();
        System.out.println("Size of list: " + apis.size());
        System.out.println(apis.get(0).getApiid());

    }
    System.out.println("GET projects query successful");
    return json + "]";
}
```

And finally, the namedQuery:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Project.queryAllUserid",
                    query = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.user.userid LIKE :userid"),
        @NamedQuery(name    = "Project.queryProjectById",
                    query   = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.projectid LIKE :projectid")
})
```

I am 100% sure the query is executing properly because all other information associated with user is returned, including all his projects and project names and ids.

I would really appreciate help and thanks again!

Comment: If I comment out any line that accesses the actual List, then the code doesn't throw error, presumably because the query does not get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First debugging pass with JPA should be always pasting the SQL in a console, replacing the placeholders `?` with sensible values and watching what happens. Second should be checking the database error information.

After my misguided comment, I just googled "DB2 " + [the error message] and got to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21236040, which contains the following text:

> SQLSTATE 42703 means:
>
> An undefined column, attribute, or parameter name was detected.

Double checking your DDL, it happens that there is no APPID column defined in your ACTIVEAPIS table (nor in the APIS) table. There is an APIID, though...